# Convert List<String> into List<Schema.SObjectField>

Tags: apex, trigger, map, sobject

I have a below code

```
public PageReference SyncCandidatewithMirror(map<Id, cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c> NewMap,Map<Id, List<String>> fieldChangedMapChanged, List<cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c> candidateList) {
     map<Schema.SObjectField,Schema.SObjectField> mapFieldWiseSchema=new map<Schema.SObjectField,Schema.SObjectField>();

        getAllMappingTable('cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c');
        list<Candidate_Mirror__c> listCandidateMirrorToUpdate=new list<Candidate_Mirror__c>();

        for(cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c can : candidateList){

            Candidate_Mirror__c mirrorCandidate = new Candidate_Mirror__c();
            for(Schema.SObjectField sjobApp:fieldChangedMapChanged.get(can.Id)){
                 Schema.SObjectField sJobAppBackup=mapFieldWiseSchema.get(sjobApp);
                 mirrorCandidate.put(sJobAppBackup, can.get(sjobApp));
            }
            listCandidateMirrorToUpdate.add(mirrorCandidate);

        }
```

Here I am passing `Map<Id, List<String>> fieldChangedMapChanged` in method.
I want to use this inside this for loop `for(Schema.SObjectField sjobApp:fieldChangedMapChanged.get(can.Id)){`

But I am getting this error **Invalid loop variable type expected String was Schema.SObjectField**. So I want to Convert `List<String>` into `List<Schema.SObjectField>`. Please anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to get Schema.SObjectField type value corresponds to a String type. No need to convert `List<String>` into `List<Schema.SObjectField>`.

```
//Get all field of cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c in a map
SObjectType objectName = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('cxsrec__cxsCandidate__c');
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = objectName.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

//Loop through fieldChangedMapChanged with a string variable
for(String sjobApp :fieldChangedMapChanged.get(can.Id)){
    //Get Schema.SObjectField type based on string value
    Schema.SObjectField sJobAppBackup = fields.get(sjobApp);
    //-----your code-----
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your map is having data type as `Map<Id, List<String>>` so `fieldChangedMapChanged.get(can.Id)` will return `List<String>` and the for loop is having a variable of type `Schema.SObjectField sjobApp`. Both need to of same data type.